# Stable variation of built-in sort

Tags: performance, ruby, sorting

Ruby's built-in sorts are *[unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517824/238886)*.  The [stable_sort](https://rubygems.org/gems/stable_sort) gem monkey-patches Ruby's built-in library to have stable sorts which include nearly all the functionality of the built-in sorts, but with the addition of *stability*.

The built-in [sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sort) method can take a block:

```
a.sort do |x, y|
  x.length <=> y.length
end
```

However, the gem's #stable_sort_by method cannot take a block (as of version 1.1).  I am adding that capability.  By simply replacing "sort" with "stable_sort", the above sort would become stable:

```
a.stable_sort do |x, y|
  x.length <=> y.length
end
```

## The code that needs improvement

My implementation is ugly, and not performant: It creates a temporary array of the same size as the original.  Here is the monkey-patch that adds Enumerable#stable_sort:

```
module Enumerable

  def stable_sort_by
    return to_enum(:stable_sort_by) if !block_given?
    sort_by.with_index{ |e, index| [yield(e), index] }
  end

  def stable_sort
    if block_given?
      # Add indices
      a = map.with_index do |e, i|
        [e, i]
      end
      # Use built-in sort.  When two elements compare the same,
      # compare the indices to break the tie
      a.sort! do |(a, i), (b, j)|
        result = yield(a, b)
        if result == 0
          i <=> j
        else
          result
        end
      end
      # Remove the indices 
      a.map(&:first)
    else
      stable_sort_by { |x| x }
    end
  end

end
```

## Supporting code

The rspec test:

```
describe Enumerable do

  KeyValue = Struct.new(:key, :value) do
    def <=> (other)
      self.key <=> other.key
    end
  end

  let (:array) { [KeyValue.new(1, 1), KeyValue.new(1, 2), KeyValue.new(1, 3), KeyValue.new(1, 4), KeyValue.new(0, 10)] }
  let (:expectation) { [KeyValue.new(0, 10), KeyValue.new(1, 1), KeyValue.new(1, 2), KeyValue.new(1, 3), KeyValue.new(1, 4)] }

  describe "#stable_sort (Array)" do
    it 'sorts stably' do
      expect(array.stable_sort.to_s).to eq expectation.to_s
    end
  end

  describe "#stable_sort (Array) (with block)" do
    it 'sorts stably' do
      array = ['a', 'c', 'bd', 'fe', 'b']
      sorted = array.stable_sort do |a, b|
        a.length <=> b.length
      end
      expect(sorted).to eq ['a', 'c', 'b', 'bd', 'fe']
    end
  end

end
```

The benchmark:

```
require "benchmark"

def iterate
  100.times { yield }
end

Benchmark.bm(16) do |x|
  Random.srand(0)
  a = Array.new(10000) { rand(100) }
  x.report("sort") do
    iterate { a.sort }
  end
  x.report("sort {}") do
    iterate { a.sort { |a, b| a <=> b } }
  end
  x.report("stable_sort") do
    iterate { a.stable_sort }
  end
  x.report("stable_sort {}") do
    iterate { a.stable_sort { |a, b| a <=> b } }
  end
end
```

And benchmark results:

```
                       user     system      total        real
sort               0.110000   0.010000   0.120000 (  0.119809)
sort {}            0.800000   0.000000   0.800000 (  0.798593)
stable_sort        2.800000   0.000000   2.800000 (  2.801303)
stable_sort {}     2.060000   0.010000   2.070000 (  2.062832) <---
```

## The question

Can stable_sort (benchmark "stable_sort {}") be made more more performant?
  Can it be made cleaner?

## Copyright notice

Portions of the above code are derived from the [stable_sort gem](https://github.com/awakia/ruby_stable_sort) which is is Copyright (c) 2013 by Naoyoshi Aikawa and released under the [MIT License](https://github.com/awakia/ruby_stable_sort/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).

Comment: Would it be possible to use `sort_by` using the index in the `block_given?` part?

Comment: @MarkThomas I don't know how to make that work.  The trouble is that the block given to #stable_sort_by doesn't return a comparable object--instead, it does the actual comparison.  #sort_by needs something comparable.

Comment: I'm guessing most of your excess time is from the unnecessary copy.  Have you tried just writing your own merge sort instead?  The gains from avoiding the copy *may* outweigh the losses from sorting in ruby rather than relying on the built-in sort in C.   You could test the hypothesis fairly quickly, anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121075/how-do-i-write-a-merge-sort

Comment: @Jonah I would be astonished if any pure-Ruby sort could beat the copy-plus-built-in sort.  Still, I hadn't thought about implementing the sort in Ruby, so that's a good idea to have.

Comment: @WayneConrad: Actually, at least Rubinius, JRuby, and especially TruffleRuby can do some amazing optimizations. TruffleRuby in particular has been known to beat hand-optimized YARV C extensions.